# Can I use name and match with a XSL template?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Snippet XML:

```
  <Time StartTime12="7:33" StartTime24="19:33" EndTime12="7:41" EndTime24="19:41">8 நிமி.</Time>
```

Snippet XSL (a template):

```
  <xsl:template match="Time">
    <td class="cellTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="@EndTime24"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Called using:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Time"/>
```

I have put the display of the end time into a template method so that I could easily change it to **EndTime12**. Then I only need to edit one bit to change from 24h to 12h.

However, my **Time** object encompasses two times as you can see. At the moment it is not an issue because all I want to do is show the end time. But if I want to show the start time on the report in another cell .... issue.

What I tried was:

```
  <xsl:template name="EndTime" match="Time">
    <td class="cellTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="@EndTime24"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Didn't work. What would be the right way to have two methods, both working on the **Time** object, but one used for displaying the **start time** attribute and the other for displaying the **end time** attribute?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear because it lacks context. In general, to have two templates match the same node (in different contexts), you would use *mode*.

Comment: The context is a schedule which will show start time, end time, item description and name of person. What is **mode**?

Comment: "*The context is  ...*" That doesn't mean much without a [mcve]. -- Re mode, see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#modes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was brought to my attention that I needed to use the **mode** feature.

```
  <!--Display the end time (using 24 hour format)-->
  <xsl:template match="Time" mode="End">
    <td class="cellTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="@EndTime24"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Display the start time (using 24 hour format)-->
  <xsl:template match="Time" mode="Start">
    <td class="cellTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="@StartTime24"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then call it with:

```
<xsl:apply-templates match="Time" mode="Start"/>
<xsl:apply-templates match="Time" mode="End"/>
```